# Preview with PHP value in dialog jquery

Tags: php, jquery, dialog

I created a div for preview with PHP and now I need to display it in Dialog Jquery,is it possible to pass directly php variable in Jquery?I tried but I have as results a blank dialog!!

Jquery side :

```
$(function() {                 
   $( "#previewDiv" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 200,
      width: 700,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
         "Submit": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            $("#submit").click();
         },
         "Cancel": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         }
      },
      close: function() {
         $('#').val("");
      }
   });

   $( "#previewButton" ).click(function() { $( "#previewDiv" ).dialog( "open" ); });
});
```

And PHP :

```
$table=$_SESSION['data'];

if (isset($_POST['preview'])) {

if ($table) { 
   foreach($table as $keys=>$values) {
      $pieces = explode(" , ",$values);
      echo "<div id='previewDiv'>"
      echo "$pieces[0]";
      echo "$pieces[1]";
      echo "</div>";
   }
}
```

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: You div identifier is `previewDiv` but you are calling the dialog with `#preview`, its normal ? May be you should try `#previewDiv`

Comment: it was previewDiv before I typed quickly!!! I correct it but it's not the reasaon why it doesn't work

Comment: Using firebug or similiar? Does console tell something?